# Module not found, but only in ipython3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I have written a package named `biographs` with the following architecture:

```
biographs (folder)
 >biographs (package)
  >__init__.py
  >bpdb.py
  >pmolecule.py
  >bgraph.py
  >bspace.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is only the following:

```
from .pmolecule import Pmolecule
```

When I'm working in ipython3 and I want to import `biographs` (only to use the class `Pmolecule`), I get the following error in ipython3 (Ipython 6.0.0, Python 3.6.1):

```
In [1]: cd ~/biographs/
/Users/rdora/biographs

In [2]: import biographs
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1803e6928e0e> in <module>()
----> 1 import biographs

/Users/rdora/biographs/biographs/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .pmolecule import Pmolecule

/Users/rdora/biographs/biographs/pmolecule.py in <module>()
      1 # class to deal with protein structures
      2 # python 2
----> 3 import bpdb
      4 import bgraph
      5 import bspace

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpdb'
```

**However** when I do exactly the same process using IPython 5.3.0 with Python 2.7.13 there is no error message.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how imports work in Python 2 and Python 3. In your module `pmolecule.py` you apparently do `import bpdb`. In Python 2 this will search the local directory for a module called `bpdb.py` and import it. However in Python 3 you must be explicit about those relative imports, i.e. you need to do

```
from . import bpdb
```

In order to get consistency for Python 2 you can use `from __future__ import absolute_imports` which prohibits such non-explicit imports also under Python 2.

Note that the same holds for:

```
----> 3 import bpdb
      4 import bgraph
      5 import bspace
```

Those need to be imported via `from . import <module-name>` syntax.

---

#### Further reading

- [What's new in Python 3 -- Removed Syntax](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax)
- [PEP 328 -- Imports: Multi-Line and Absolute/Relative](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)